# AS3 - Make a text grow on hover

Tags: actionscript-3

I want the text to grow when hovering over it, I understand how to add the event listener and detect when it's being hovered over, just don't understand how to actually execute the growing part.
I don't want it immediately skipping from one size to another either, I want it to actually show it growing, basically it will quickly grow to lets say 2x the normal size if you hover over it, these are the buttons for the home screen so I want the buttons to be noticeable when you are hovering over it.

```
public function _H_o(_arg1:String, _arg2:int, _arg3:Boolean) {
    name = _arg1;
    this.text_ = new SimpleText(_arg2, 0xD85A00, false, 0, 0, "Myriad Pro");
    this.text_.setBold(true);
    this.text_.text = _arg1.toLowerCase();
    this.text_.updateMetrics();
    this.text_.filters = [new DropShadowFilter(0, 0, 0, 0.5, 12, 12)];
    addChild(this.text_);
    this._U_r = _arg3;
    this._0H_X_ = width;
    this._N_a = height;
    this.activate();
}
public function activate():void{
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, this.onMouseOver2);
    this.active = true;
} 
protected function onMouseOver2(_arg1:MouseEvent):void {
    //the code that makes the text medium-paced grow to 2x it size
}
```

Comment: One possible approach is to tween the size of the font on hover. Or Tween the whole textbox. What i'm trying to say is: Use [Tweening](https://greensock.com/tweenlite-as) I reccomend the Greensock library.

Comment: @DodgerThud I'll check it out now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic example using [greensock](https://greensock.com/) as twinning library:

```
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
    private var _textField:TextField;
    private var _textFormat:TextFormat;

    public function Main() 
    {
        _textField = new TextField();
        _textFormat = new TextFormat();
        _textFormat.size = 50;

        _textField.defaultTextFormat = _textFormat;
        _textField.text = "text";

        addChild(_textField);

        //repeat -1 so the animation continue forever
        //yoyo to go both ways from the begining to the end and  from the end to the begining
        TweenMax.to(_textFormat, 1, {size:10, yoyo:true, repeat: -1, onUpdate:updateTextSize});
    }

    private function updateTextSize():void 
    {
        //text needs to be preset again
        _textField.text = "text";
        _textField.defaultTextFormat = _textFormat;
        trace(_textFormat.size);
    }
}
```

I hope it helps you.